# Keras/TensorFlow GPU -- Stuck at Epoch 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I am struggling to set up a simple deep learning code to run on my GPU.

The code is a simple CNN from the cifar10 dataset (copy/past from https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-cnn-from-scratch-for-cifar-10-photo-classification/).

When I check if it does find the GPU:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

I get:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 1854574019269825039
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 23174440576
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 269960360402377625
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 3090, pci bus id: 0000:65:00.0, compute capability: 8.6"
]
```

It does find cuda and cudnn but get stuck at Epoch 1:

```
2021-04-11 22:09:18.343347: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-04-11 22:09:18.363546: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:112] CPU Frequency: 3699850000 Hz
Epoch 1/100
2021-04-11 22:09:18.915658: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
2021-04-11 22:09:19.399116: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
2021-04-11 22:09:19.401652: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
```

If you have any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hard to do a remote dignosis with so little info, but did you try to run your code on Google Colab - there you can enable/disable GPU support, to check if it really is the GPU config that is blocking execution?

Comment: @Maxime Carriere, Can you let us know Tensorflow Version? If you are not using `TF 2.4`, then try with this version?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use pip version instead use conda I did this and worked for me:

```
conda create -n tf-gpu
conda activate tf-gpu
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow-gpu
```

then install nessecary packages